# Rails combining search and taggings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm working on a map app and I want a feature where user can search by  entering a keyword plus clicking a tag at the same time. This should display all the users with that tags around that area. This is how it looks:

user_controller.rb

```
  def index
    if params[:search].present?
      @users = User.near(params[:search], 10, units: :mi)
    elsif params[:tag].present?
      @users = User.tagged_with(params[:tag], :match_all => true)
    else
      @users = User.all
    end
  end
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
<%= submit_tag "Search" %>

<div id="tag_cloud">
  <% tag_cloud User.tag_counts_on(:tags).order("name ASC"), %w[s m l] do |tag, css_class| %>
  <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag:(tag.name), class: css_class) %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of your needs since your question lacks an actual question, but why don't you just simply chain your requests? I.e.:

```
def index
  @users = User.all 
  @users = @users.near(params[:search], 10, units: :mi) if params[:search].present?
  @users = @users.tagged_with(params[:tag], :match_all => true) if params[:tag].present?
end
```

Comment: Thanks but that's what i've done though in my controller. I want to be able to filter using search and tag at the same time

Comment: This is exactly what the code I posted does? Read it again, it's different than what you posted.